# Can I get the final HTML output of a route in ASP.NET MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Is there a way to get the "final HTML output" (what you get when you do "View source" in a browser) from code in ASP.NET MVC3 without making use of something like a WebRequest?

For example something like this:

```
string htmlCode = Url.GetHtml("Action", "Controller", new { id = 7 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this with RazorGenerator.Mvc which is available as a Nuget package. You can read more about it here: http://razorgenerator.codeplex.com/ It was intended for Unit testing but I think it is what your looking for.

```
var view = new myview();
HtmlDocument document = view.RenderAsHtml();
```

Hope that helps you in what your trying to do.

Comment: There is no `RenderAsHtml` method in MVC

Comment: True I forgot that you need to install the RazorGenrator package. Added info about that

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
public static string ViewToString(string viewName, object model)
{
    ViewData.Model = model;
    using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
    {
        var view = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, viewName);
        var viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, view.View, ViewData, TempData, stringWriter);
        view.View.Render(viewContext, stringWriter);
        view.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(ControllerContext, view.View);
        return stringWriter.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: That renders a view belonging to the same controller as it's being invoked from. The question shows an example that specified an arbitrary controller.